# Will Ubuntu live cd/dvd work with no hard drive installed?

Tags: live-cd

I have no hard drive installed, Only USB thumb drive. Will this be a problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It will work just fine. I've often used it as a tool to diagnose computers with hard drives that have quit working.

If you want to save stuff, you could plug in a thumb drive or a USB hard drive and save it to that. A thumb drive will show up just like it would on a normal Ubuntu install.

Another option if you want persistence is to make a LiveUSB drive with Ubuntu's startup disk creator and use the option to have persistence.

Comment: Exactly, just what I needed.   So the system would be running 2GB ram and run a live USB with persistence, lets say 8gb thumbdrive.   Would this work. IYO

Comment: Should work just fine. Do note that persistence doesn't seem to store things like packages installed. It just seems to keep stuff in the home folder.

Comment: Does the live disk need to write to the thumb drive? Is it possible to run a live disk with no write privileges at all?

Answer (score 5):

It should work fine, I've used a live CD on machines with totally broken hard drives with no problem.

If you want persistence you'll need to boot off a USB key instead of a CD.

Comment: This would be a good thing. Is there a persistence while using the CD/DVD

Comment: The CD will be mounted read-only, so no. Any changes are lost on reboot.

Answer (score 5):

As long as you have RAM go for it, a LiveCD does not need a hard disk or even a writable media installed to run properly.

Comment: is 2GB enough to run Natty

Comment: 2GB is enough. The whole Ubuntu install is 2GB as far as I know, and you won't be needing all that at once, so yeah.