# Running ubuntu from LIveCD with no harddisk

Tags: boot, hard-drive, live-cd

can i boot Linus from LiveCD into a copmuter system where computer system doesnot have a physical hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. The live CD uses RAM, not the harddrive.

I see this is a duplicate: [Will Ubuntu live cd/dvd work with no hard drive installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104003/will-ubuntu-live-cd-dvd-work-with-no-hard-drive-installed)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact reason why you would do that.  But, as Private answer stated, Yes you can.  You can even install some programs. It all depends on the amount of RAM you have in your machine.

I would recommend that you run Ubuntu from a USB flash drive, specially if you`re planning on downloading any applications that you would like to save, either for late use or if planning to move it to another machine.